# Unable to get Azure-Media-Services Access-Token in JS

Tags: javascript, access-token, azure-media-services

I followed [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-connect-programmatically/) to connect to Azure via Rest where the first step is to get an access-token for the service. So i tried to send the following request:

```
POST https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net
Content-Length: 120
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ams_account_name&client_secret=URL_encoded_ams_account_key&scope=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices
```

and replaced the client_id and key(encoded) in the data to be posted.

But Chrome promptly complains about setting the unsafe Host-, Content-Length-, Connection- and Expect-Headers. So i omitted those and end up with the following:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.send("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<id>&client_secret=<encodedSecret>scope=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices");
```

now upon sending the request i get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://nope.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

*But* the request works when i send it through the Rest Client, Fiddler and requestmaker.com which i take as evidence that the request is formed correctly ...

Any hint as to how i can get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (generated from POSTMAN)

```
var data = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<ACOUNTNAME>&client_secret=<ACCOUNTKEY>&scope=urn%3AWindowsAzureMediaServices";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("host", "wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net");
xhr.setRequestHeader("connection", "Keep-Alive");
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(data);
```

In Postman, i have to have the Interceptor plugin enabled for this to work though, and disable Automatically Follow Redirects.  See if that helps at all.

After you get the response back and parsed the access_token, you can use it in the next call to get the closest API endpoint like this

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://media.windows.net/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version", "2.11");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");


xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Well, now i know that the request works in Postman as well(didn't need to edit any settings though). However, i did try the generated code from Postman and even that doesn't work in Chrome ... still the same error message.  But Thanks for the response anyway^^

Comment: Let me see if i can repro this. Do you have any sample code in github to point to?  Just so I'm clear, you are trying to call this code from within Chrome and not in Node.JS on the backend? (how exactly are you securing your creds?)

Comment: Also note - the issue appears to be a security issue - CORS.

Comment: yes, i just tried to execute this in the chrome dev tools because this should be used as part of client side project later on. the sample code, including the service account and key, can be found there: http://pastebin.com/Vcq3FKdv and the thing that is still puzzling to me is that sending the request with the same options through client applications works even though i expected to get some cors error message there as well.